# Create an array containing multiple key: value pairs, where the value is an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, associative-array

What I want to achieve is something like this :

**let bigArray = [ key1 => [], key2 => [], key3 => [] ];**

Where bigArray would be an array containing in this case 3 arrays with specific names/keys.
I don't want to use a map, and would like to access and manopulate the array values this way :

let array1 = bigArray.key1;

bigArray.key1.push("item");

I have been trying for about an hour looking on the internet for this exact situation but I haven't been able to find the way to do exactly this in typescript, so I was hoping someone experimentend in TypeScript could help me out on this one ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: let bigArray = { key1: [], key2: [], key3: [] };

Which obviously is not an array..

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: If one needs to do: `let array1 = bigArray.key1;`, then `bigArray` may need to be an `object` which has a prop `key1`. If `bigArray` was an array, then to access the elements one will need to use: `bigArray[0]`, or `bigArray[1]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exact use case you are looking for, but if you want to access the arrays by key it should be a map. If it's just an array of array's you'd have to use index to find the location. Map lets you assign array to key, easily find and search for data. Here is a small example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  map = new Map<String, []>();

  constructor() {
    this.map.set('sss', ['sss', 'asdasd']);
    this.map.set('aaa', ['sss', '1123']);
    this.map.set('sass', ['sss']);
    this.map.set('xxx', ['sss']);
    this.map.set('ss', ['sss']);

    this.map.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
      console.log(key, value);
    });

    this.getKeys;

    this.getValues;

    this.getKey('xxx');
  }

  getKey(key: string) {
    console.log('I am single key: ', this.map.get(key));
  }

  getKeys(map) {
    console.log('I am array of keys: ', Array.from(map.keys()));
  }

  getValues(map) {
    console.log('I am array of values: ', Array.from(map.values()));
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-array-from-gqxdgu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts